# Bluemix Connect and Compose : Is there any way to add nodes?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, connect-compose

In Bluemix service - Connect and Compose, is there any way to add nodes to Node-RED pallets e.g. MQ Light, Cloudant? For example, my APIs assume to hold sessions and exchange messages to worker process via MQ Light and this needs to be added as a Node.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add nodes". You can add your own nodes to Node-Red, you can modify them. Some description is here http://nodered.org/docs/

Answer (score 3):

No, the beta version of the Connect and Compose service does not let you customise the Node-RED instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll call restapi through HTTP request node for the time being. I believe pallet can be dynamically change though admin api. So It would be very useful to add features to dynamically add "nodes" in stead of package.json.